# Python string match

Tags: regex, string, python

If a string contains `*SUBJECT123`, how do I determine that the string has `subject` in it in python?

Comment: What is the relevance of "If a string contains *SUBJECT123"? Do you mean "How do I do a case-insensitive search"?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
if "subject" in mystring.lower():
  # do something
```

Comment: you can use the lower() method

Answer (score 12):

If you want to have `subject` match `SUBJECT`, you could use [`re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

```
import re
if re.search('subject', your_string, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Or you could transform the string to lower case first and simply use:

```
if "subject" in your_string.lower()
```

Answer (score 7):

Just another way

```
mystring.find("subject")
```

the above answers will return true if the string contains "subject" and false otherwise. While find will return its position in the string if it exists else a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

```
if "*SUGJECT123" in mystring and "subject" in mystring:
    # do something
```