# Search user input from a string and print

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have a string called `new_file` that I read from a file with these contents:

```
;ASP718I
;AspA2I
;AspBHI 0 6 9 15 ...
;AspCNI
;AsuI 37 116 272 348
...
```

I am using `name = raw_input ("enter the enzyme  ")`
to get data from the user and I am trying to print the corresponding fields from the above file (new_file).

For the input `;AspBHI` I'd like the program to print the corresponding line from the file:

`;AspBHI 0 6 9 15 ...`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So, What's the problem? where did you get stuck ?

Comment: I dont know how to find the string after the user input is given .how will i be able to achieve ;AspS9I 37 116 272 348

Comment: start with http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm then check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351218/python-string-match and you will have your soloution....

Comment: how can I take the user input , search the string from the " new_file" and print it in a text file

Comment: If the user gives an input ;AspS9I , how can i search and print ;AspS9I 37 116 272 348

Comment: Do you have a choice of how new_file is formated?

Answer (score 1):

This is a start:

```
db = dict((x.split(" ")[0], x) for x in new_file.split("\n"))
name = raw_input("enter the enzyme ")
print db[name]
```

Also try to be nice next time, people might help you with more enthusiasm and even explain their approach.